# How to handle if else nested statment in dataweave in mulesoft

Tags: mule

OptIn: "Yes" when payload.country==true and payload.state==false otherwise "No" when payload.country==false and payload.state==true otherwise "NOT VALID" when payload.country==false and payload.state==false otherwise ""

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieve through following example :-

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="DataweaveFlow">
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/poc" doc:name="HTTP"/>

 <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[ %dw 1.0 
 %input payload application/json         
 %output application/json 
--- 

         { value1: "Yes" } when payload.country==true and payload.state==false
         otherwise (
         { value1: "No" } when payload.country==false and payload.state==true
             otherwise (
             { value1: "NOT VALID" } when payload.country==false and payload.state==false

                 otherwise "your value"

                 ))]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
 <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

</flow>
```

Where I tested this with following input :-
case 1:-

```
{
"country":true,
"state":false
}
```

case 2:-

```
{
"country":false,
"state":true
}
```

case 3:-

```
{
"country":false,
"state":false
}
```

case 4:-

```
{
"country":true,
"state":"default value"
}
```